# Delay a gearman job in php

Tags: php, message-queue, gearman

I have a Gearman Work in php that processes background tasks from client. From time to time I am not able to process that job. I would need a way to delay retry that job after 5 minutes. How can I do that?

What I do now is to do `exit(255`) but this will retry the job immediately. Also I do not know how can I get the number of failures of that specific job (in the worker).

Questions:

1. How can I do the above stuff in Gearmand
2. Is there any other
   messageing system that is capable of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. At least not using built-in capabilities. This feature is only partly implemented in Gearmand and the PHP module does not expose this functionality. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gearman/woe7YN0SWZk) on the feature.

People have tried different things, including:

- Use [node.js and its timeout capabilities](http://code.recollect.com/post/12792504787/queue-within-a-queue)
- Use `at` [utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547538/schedule-a-job-in-gearman-for-a-specific-date-and-time)
- Use another queuing system - [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/)

When it comes to tracking failures - again, you can't, AFAIK. See my answer on [handling retries in Gearman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870132/error-conditions-and-retries-in-gearman-error-conditions-and-retries-in-gearman/10348461#10348461) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not build in, but you can use a bit of memcached+TTL for that.